# how to display frame of video in new window at a given time using qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Here is my code .in this code video is displaying in main window not in new window. I want to display frame of  video in new window at a given time means at 90 sec

```
 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    if(ui->radioButton_2->isChecked()) {

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
              tr("Open Video"), "G://", "All files (*.*);Video files(*.*)");
     ui->lineEdit->setText(fileName);


         player = new QMediaPlayer;
            vw=new QVideoWidget;
          player->setVideoOutput(vw) ;

           player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
           QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
               QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
               layout->addWidget(vw);
             dialog->open();
          vw->show();
         player->play();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this->setCentralWidget(vw);` you have to create a dialog and add your video widgets to that and then show the dialog. To do that, please follow theses steps one by one:

1. Add a `QDialog` to your project with the following `.cpp` and `.h` files:

Dialog.h

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QVideoWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog();

    void playVideo(const QString &fileName);

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e) override;

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QVBoxLayout *lay;
    QMediaPlayer *player;
    QVideoWidget *vw;

};
```

Dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::playVideo(const QString &fileName)
{
    player = new QMediaPlayer;
    vw=new QVideoWidget;
    lay = new QVBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(vw);
    player->setVideoOutput(vw) ;
    setLayout(lay);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
    open();
    vw->show();
    player->play();
}

void Dialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    player->stop();
    delete player;
    delete vw;
    delete lay;
}
```

1. Then, modify `Mainwindow.h` as follows:
   2-1. Include your new dialog as `#include "dialog.h"`
   2-2. In the `private:` section, define `Dialog *dialog;`
2. Modify `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()` as follows:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                    tr("Open Video"), "C://", "All files (*.*);Video files(*.*)");

    dialog->playVideo(fileName);
}
```

Comment: video is displaying in new window but i have to select two times on push button.For first time clicking on push button video is not displaying.second time clicking on push button, two new window is opened- one is blanked and other is displaying video.

Comment: I have to extract frame at given time in this time is not specified.

Comment: Why the first click does not display it? Maybe your video is a large file, isn't it? Even if you wait for a while, it does not work? Could you post your code after the above modification?

Comment: yes it is large file, yes if i wait it does not work....if i press second times push button and select file again then it display video file here is my code

Comment: I modified my answer to completely solve your problem. This code runs successfully on my machine. I hope solves your problem. Please modify your code based on my answer and see if the problem resolves. If so, please mark this answer as "Solved" to help others as well.

Comment: In my computer this code is not working...it shows videogui.exe has stopped working

Comment: Please double check your implementation and specially your pointers. If you give more details I may can find the problem. Please let me know your machine configurations as well.

Comment: its a window 10 machine